# how to delete queues using rabbitmq batch files

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I am using rabbitmq version 3.6.9. I don't see rabbitmqadmin in the sbin folder. Can anyone please tell me on where I can find this.

I enabled rabbitmq_management as below

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate binary for `rabbitmqadmin` on windows,
see the official [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html):

`Windows users will need to ensure Python is on their path, and invoke rabbitmqadmin as python.exe rabbitmqadmin.`